# Why does Dart's default sort implementation beat my key-sorter?

Tags: sorting, dart

I thought I was being clever I implemented a sorter which does not use a comparing function that simply recalculates the sort-score of the compared elements each iteration, but rather calculates the scores (I call them keys) once and caches them. For me that seemed to be contraire to what the dart default implementation (or for that matter, also the Java implementation) does.

Anyway, here is my implementation:

```dart
class KeySorter<V, K extends Comparable> {

  List<V> list;

  KeySorter(this.list);

  List<V> sort(K keyFn(V)) {
    Map<V, K> keys = {};
    list.sort((e1, e2) {
      var e1Key = keys.putIfAbsent(e1, () => keyFn(e1)),
          e2Key = keys.putIfAbsent(e2, () => keyFn(e2));
      return e1Key.compareTo(e2Key);
    });

    return list;
  }
}
```

And that's the benchmark:
https://gist.github.com/Gregoor/547c0451c4fa527dd85c

The default implementation beats mine by a factor of 4. How comes?

Comment: Did you try with a keyFn that is more expensive to calculate? As it is it looks like the time required to set/retrieve the map values could dwarf the time it takes to calculate the key value

Comment: Caching the keyFn results only makes sense if looking the key up in the cache is significantly faster than recomputing it. Using a Map has some overhead too, and definitely more than a few arithmetic operations and if-statements.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes an awful lot of sense. I guess I was to deep in the tree, to find the woods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, caching only makes sense if it takes less time to create and look up the cache than to calculate the result from scratch.

Your implementation also artificially slows down the cache look-up by using `putIfAbsent` unnecessarily. Replacing this with an initial cache population followed by a direct key lookup reduces the performance difference to only a factor of 2:

```dart
List<V> sort(K keyFn(V)) {
  Map<V, K> keys = {};
  list.forEach((e) => keys[e] = keyFn(e));
  list.sort((e1, e2) {
    return keys[e1].compareTo(keys[e2]);
  });

  return list;
}
```

Comment: But that would slow it down in cases where there are duplicates in the list, wouldn't it? So overall the comparing function is recommended for easy calculations, your solution for difficult calculations without or few duplicates and mine for cases where there are multiple duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct, but I am not sure how many duplicates would be required to make it the faster option.